# I dont know why my code isn't counting the last 2 values

Tags: python, compression

I'm trying to make a code (for school) that compresses and counts the number of adjacent characters that are the same. in this example it would be 4(1) 4(0) 2(1) 2(0).  it is supposed to output: 4 4 2 2 but for some reason, it leaves out the last 2.

does anyone know how to fix this or make my code more optimised?

my code:

```
val = "111100001100"  #the value
count1 = 0  #counts how many repeated values there are
count0 = 0
num = 0
char = val[num]
char_count = 0
length = len(val)
l1 = length - 1 

for char in range(l1):
  if val[char + 1] == val[char]:
    count1 += 1
    char_count + 1
  elif val[char + 1] != val[char]:
    x = str(count1 + 1)
    print(x)
    count1 = 0
    char_count + 1*
```

the output:
4
4
2

Comment: you havent provided any code

Comment: you are only printing x when the next characther is not the same as the current iteration index. so the last two will never pass the last condition since they are both the same.

Comment: `char_count` will never be increased in that way (and last line has a strange `*` characters)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby).

To see how it works, here is what it does to your `val`:

```
print([(k, list(v)) for k,v in itertools.groupby(val)])

[('1', ['1', '1', '1', '1']),
 ('0', ['0', '0', '0', '0']),
 ('1', ['1', '1']),
 ('0', ['0', '0'])]
```

To get your desired output, we only need to get the length of the list for each group.

```
print(*[len(list(v)) for k,v in itertools.groupby(val)])

4 4 2 2
```

If you want it to do it your way, I made some little changes to make it work. You could add an extra condition to check if it is the last element in the list and then print the current value of `count1`.

```
val = "111100001100"  #the value

count1 = 0  #counts how many repeated values there are
length = len(val) # 12

for char in range(length):
    if not char==length-1:
        if (val[char + 1] != val[char]):
            x = str(count1 + 1)
            print(x)
            count1 = 0
        elif val[char+1] == val[char]:
            count1 += 1
    else:
        x = str(count1 + 1)
        print(x)
```

```
4 4 2 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution:

```
val = "111100001100"  #the value

resultKeys = [] #Stores the characters themselves
result = [] #Use a list for easier scalability

temp = None #Initializes an empty variable

for i in val:
    if temp != i: #If this is true, a new character is found compared to the last iteration
        temp = i  #Let the program know the current character
        result.append(1) #Add a new entry to your results
        resultKeys.append(i) #Store the character to your keys
    else:
        result[len(result) - 1] += 1  #If it is not a new character, add 1 to the current entry of your results

print(resultKeys, \n, result )
```

> Output: ['1', '0', '1', '0']
> [4, 4, 2, 2]

As you can see, the result list contains the count of the adjacent characters. The resultKeys list contains the order in which your characters are. If you place them above one another, you can see which character is counted in each place of your result.
E.g. resultKeys[0] has value '1', result[0] has value 4
--> The first character of your input is a 1 and it occurs 4 times in a row